# Outlook add-in. getCallbackTokenAsync returns AccessRestricted

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

MS - I'm trying to develop the own add-id on Mac and stuck with the issue getting Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync for REST API calls 
I'm getting the

```
{"value":null,"status":"failed","error":{"name": "AccessRestricted", "message": "Internal protocol error: '-2147467259'."}}
```

What could be the reasons why I'm getting it?

Comment: Can you please mention which version of the API you are using?

Comment: Are you still facing this issue? If yes, can you provide following details: 
1. Can you share a code snippet for the your call to getCallbackTokenAsync? So we can try to repro the issue at our end.
2. What is permission level for you addin ?

Comment: The API
`const OUTLOOK_API_URL = 'https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0';`

The snippet 
`
init() {
        Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync({ isRest: true }, (result) => {
            if (result.status === AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                this.jwtToken = result.value;
            }
        });
    }
`

Comment: This is how manifest looks like
`< xmlns="...1.1">
  <Reqs>
    ...
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1"/>
    ...
  </Reqs>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      ...
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule  Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Edit"/>
  </Rule>
  <VersionOverrides xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Reqs>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox"/>
      </bt:Sets>
    </Reqs>
    ...
  </VersionOverrides>
</>`

Comment: The manifest implies that the Add-in is working in Appointment-Compose mode. If you are invoking the getCallbackTokenAsync() API for Meeting Compose, save the item prior to the API call and let us know if the API works.

Comment: Sample code to save the item prior to getCallBackTokenAsync() call:

Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync(function (result) {
  if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
   Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync(function (result) {
    if (result.status !== Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
        console.error(JSON.stringify(result));
    } else {
        console.log(result.value);
    }
});
  }
  else {
    console.error(`saveAsync failed with message ${result.error.message}`);
  }
});

Comment: Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync returns me:

code: 5000
message: "The operation is not supported."
name: "Host Error"

Comment: We understand that the platform in which you are experiencing this issue is Mac and SaveAsync API for Meeting Compose is not currently supported in Mac. This is the reason for 'Host Error'. 
To resolve the issue with getCallbackTokenAsync, you can update the permission in manifest as ‘ReadWriteMailbox’ and get the REST Token without saving the Item.

Comment: Thanks a lot folks - i was able to get token :)
Now i'm trying to call findmeetingtimes (2.0 api)
Unless looks i have required scope - i get 403 AccessDenied response
`"scp": "Mail.ReadWrite Mail.Send Calendars.ReadWrite Contacts.ReadWrite",`

What could be the reason?

Comment: Can you share complete manifest for us? As you must have found out findmeetingtimes requires calendars.read.shared permission scope. This means that REST token which you acquire must have this scope as well. This means that your manifest must have SupportSharedFolders. Please check if it has this manifest attribute set.